# Can I query a Firestore database by GeoPoint values to find local places?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I'm wondering if this is possible, as I've searched for quite a while and not found any documentation that shows that a query can be made against stored GeoPoints in Firestore from Android in Java?

Comment: check https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I query a Firestore database by GeoPoint values to find local places?

Sure you can. If you want to query Firestore by a specific GeoPoint object, then you should [perform a Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query). Assuming that you have in the database a document that has a property of type GeoPoint which holds, for example, `51.5074` for latitude and `0.1278` for longitude, then the following query is required:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference placesRef = rootRef.collection("places");
Query geoQuery = placesRef.whereEqualTo("geoPoint", new GeoPoint(51.5074, 0.1278));
geoQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

However, if you want to query nearby locations, please note that Firebase recently launched [Geo queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries), meaning that you can get documents that would fall into a specific radius.

Comment: Thanks Alex - exactly what I'm after! I've managed to store some GeoHashes and query them by location very easily. [This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/mx1mMdHBi5Q?t=1320)  by a Google engineer, starting at 22:00 was also helpful to learn about GeoHashes.

Comment: @thomas_roe You're very welcome, Thomas. I know that video, yes, it's really helpful.